# Inicialização em programação

Tags: android

bom dia, sou o ser mais iniciante que se possa imaginar em programação. Gostaria de aprender a fazer/conhecer softwares para Smartfones (Apple, Android e Windows) mas não sei nem por onde começar, vcs podem me dar dicas de como começar? O que devo saber? Dicas de sites que tenham literaturas, etc, etc.

Sou formado em Engenharia Elétrica.

Abraços for all

Comment: Pergunta fora de escopo, tão conteúdo poderia ser esclarecido no chat.

Comment: Ele não tem reputação para usar o chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procure entender e estudar antes de tudo, paradigmas.

Tecnologias seguem paradigmas, como orientação a objetos, eventos, sequencial e etc. O importante é você entender o que você está escrevendo, saber planejar e projetar antes de escrever ou pior, copiar algo que você poderia ter feito melhor. A principal característica de um bom desenvolvedor é entender o problema e ter a solução antes de escrever qualquer coisa.

Dessa forma, entendo que você deva começar por cursos introdutórios a Orientação a Objetos, Design Patterns e Lógica de Programação. Isso é o suficiente pra começar e depois aplicar em qualquer linguagem, Java, Groovy, Python, C# e etc.

Após isso você vai conseguir se guiar de uma forma muito mais objetiva, o caminho das pedras irá se tornar mais proveitoso.

Comment: Obrigado Guiandmag

Answer (score -1):

Bem, já que você quer entrar diretamente no desenvolvimento mobile, as vídeo aulas desse canal são as melhores para novatos: [Link Vídeos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIMMpAKHWdp8Vf2vMuuLX8Q).
Ele já abordou android e está começando com Windows Phone agora. Um livro muito bom sobre android é o do Ricardo Lecheta, sem dúvida o melhor nacional: [Link Livro](http://www.livroandroid.com.br/pages/livro-android.php). Porém, como ele mesmo diz no livro, é necessário saber um pouco de java para entender bem o livro, por isso te indico um livro básico de java, o Use a Cabeça! Java: [Link Livro](http://www.buscape.com.br/use-a-cabeca-java-kathy-sierra-8576081733.html).

Sites sobre android, windows phone e iOS existem vários, mas o único que eu conheço bem e indico é esse: [Link Site](http://www.vogella.com/), que é sobre android e java.

Acho que com essas referências você já tem conteúdo bom e para um bom tempo de estudo.